# set total number of records datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatable, rows

i'm using the plugin [datatables](https://datatables.net/) for paginate the querys into my server but the problem came when i want say to `.DataTable` the total records that i get with a count (query) of my controller.

i tryed to search in google, into the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/api), and include here in stackoverflow and i didn't find it.

Any idea?

PS: this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#resultados').DataTable( {
            //"recordsTotal": 45,
            'bFilter': false, 
            'bInfo': false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            'ajax' : {
               "url": '<?php echo base_url();?>Comercial/getTar/?fail=0',
               "type": 'POST',
               "data": { //for search
                   Name: 'aaaaa test 1',
                   Date: 'aaaaa jjjj 2'
                }
            },
            'columns':[
                {"data":'Name'},
                {'data':'Date'},
                {'data':'AnotherInfo'}
            ]
        } );
```

Comment: Why don't you do it at server side? Anyway, I read the documentation there is an option: `pageLength` _Change the initial page length (number of rows per page)_. You can find it here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Comment: i want say not the number of rows per page, the total number of rows.

Comment: for example: i show 10 records but i have 2035 records in total (it's for the pagination take the numbers exactly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you use server side processing for large datasets as it's difficult to process large amounts of data locally.

For a similar case I suggest taking a look at 
[Serverside Pagination Example](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

Comment: the problem came that i take the info of my server from a query with limit and i return 10 to 10 all the registers.

Comment: all the querys are ready for make it of this way. and i get automatically the count of the registers into the first query